# Push notifications: Apple’s reliability requirements

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am trying to use both environments for the push notifications: sandbox and production. Everything works in the sandbox, but not in the production.

In the Push Notification Programming Guide it is written:
    Applications using the production environment must meet Apple’s reliability requirements.

I suspect that this might be the problem. Does anyone know what are those reliability requirements?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that there's a way to quantify reliability in this context. 
If you are concerned that your server might not be reliable enough for Apple's requirements, consider using a third party service, like Urban Airship.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same device ID in both sandbox and production? The production server uses different device IDs to the sandbox one so this might be causing the problem.